# When to load an async relation with Flux

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

Let's say you have a Pet component displaying a pet resource. You also have an owner resource that belongs to pet via an ownerId attribute. Where in the Pet component should you load the owner resource?

```
const Pet = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            pet: PetStore.get(this.props.petId)
        };
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        PetStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    },

    componentWillUnmount() {
        PetStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
    },

    render() {
        var owner; // where should I initiate the ajax request to get owner? 

        return (
            <p>{owner.name}</p>
        );
    },

    onChange() {
        this.setState({
            pet: PetStore.get(this.props.petId)
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thilo mentioned, the React documentation suggests that you do asynchronous loading of data in `componentDidMount`. The reason for doing it on `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` is that `componentWillMount` will get executed if you run React on the server for the initial page load, and you don't want to make Ajax calls on the server.

With that said, I would recommend that you move your data fetching logic to another component (often called view controller in the React world). This means that instead of having one component doing both data fetching and rendering, you have two components. One whos responsibility is to fetch data, and the other is to render that data. You'd pass that data as props to the rendering component from the view controller component. A small example would be:

```
var Pet = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Pet: {this.props.pet.name}</p>
      <p>Owner: {this.props.owner.name}</p>
    );
  }
});

var PetController = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      pet: PetStore.get(this.props.petId),
      owner: null
    };
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    OwnerStore.getOwner(this.state.pet.ownerId)
      .then(owner => this.setState({owner: owner}));
  },
  render() {
    return <Pet pet={this.state.pet} owner={this.state.owner} />;
  }
});
```

What this separation gives you is simpler and more focused components. The `Pet` component doesn't have to worry about where to get the data, and it can be reused in other cases where you get the data from some place other than the `PetStore`. And the `PetController` component focuses only on data fetching and state management. To make the `Pet` component even simpler, you can avoid rendering it until the owner is fetched. Something like:

```
var PetController = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      pet: PetStore.get(this.props.petId),
      owner: null
    };
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    OwnerStore.getOwner(this.state.pet.ownerId)
      .then(owner => this.setState({owner: owner}));
  },
  render() {
    if (this.state.pet && this.state.owner) {
      return <Pet pet={this.state.pet} owner={this.state.owner} />;
    } else {
      return <div className="spinner" />;
    }
  }
});
```

Then your `Pet` component doesn't have to worry about asynchronous data fetching because it won't get rendered until the data is there.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I notice you're returning a promise from your call to OwnerStore.getOwner. You wouldn't initiate the request in an action creator and then listen to the store for updates?

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but that tends to make the store layer a bit messy because you have to keep track of what all components are currently interested in. And you also have to keep track of when that changes. I find it simpler to just tell my components that something changed, and let the component pull what it needs again from the store. But not everyone agrees with me here, there seem to be a lot of variations in how people interpret Flux.

Comment: Just an extra comment because I've been burned by it a few times.. Anytime you perform an async action and then update state, make sure you check `this.isMounted() === true` before calling `setState`. The virtual DOM node outlives the real DOM node and if the component isn't mounted, it'll blow an exception

Comment: Very interesting - I've been trying to wrap my brain around this as well. This seems to push asynchronous data fetching into the store though the majority of sources I've seen are recommending instead to have Stores be totally synchronous and push data fetching into the Action Creators. Do I have that right?

Comment: I keep the stores synchronous ya. It generally makes things much simpler to reason about and more unit testable. Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29868686/3219447

Comment: Interesting discussion. I don't use actions for initiating fetching data because actions are things that modifies state. In HTTP, that would be POST, PUT, DELETE, etc. Fetching data is a GET, so I don't want to mix that with things that change state. I can live with having one extra line in my component to deal with promises.

Answer (score 0):

The React [documentation recommends](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) doing this in `componentDidMount`.