# Javascript ajax library supporting global events

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, request, reactjs

Which **ajax library** should I use for my React/Flux app? I need to globally handle errors (e.g. automatically logout and redirect to login if 401; similar to $http service in Angular) and I would like to use promises.

Answer (score 1):

The way I'm currently doing it is a combination of three libraries:

1. [Reflux.js](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs)
2. [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)
3. jQuery

*webutils.js*

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = {
  makeApiCall: function() {
    return Promise.resolve($.get("http://makeyourapicall"));
  }
};
```

*actions.js:*

```
var Reflux = require('reflux');
var WebUtils = require('web-utils.js');

var Actions = Reflux.createActions({
  getDataFromServer: { asyncResult: true } 
});

Actions.getDataFromServer.listenAndPromise(WebUtils.makeApiCall);

module.exports = Actions;
```

Explanation:

- The `asyncResult: true` in the `createActions` call creates a "nested/asynchronous action" that you can listen to. [More Here](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs#asynchronous-actions)
- The `listenAndPromise` function hooks a promise up to the nested `completed` and `failed` callbacks based on the result

You can consume the nested actions like this:

```
Actions.getDataFromServer.complete.listen(res => console.log('success', res));

Actions.getDataFromServer.failed.listen(err => console.log('failed', err));
```

In that sense we can implement a universal error handler by hooking up to all the `.failed` events.

*reflux-error-handler.js*

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var Reflux = require('reflux');
var NotificationStore = require('../stores/NotificationStore');

/**
 * Overall error handler for async actions
 * @param err
 */
function handleError(err) {
  console.error('Encountered error:', err);
  NotificationStore.createErrorNotification(err);
}

/**
 * Loops over refluxActions and attaches an error handler to all async actions
 * @param refluxActions {Object} hash of the reflux actions ot generate
 * @constructor
 */
var RefluxErrorHandler = function(refluxActions) {
  _.forEach(refluxActions, func => {
    if(func.failed) {
      func.failed.listen(handleError);
    }
  });
  return refluxActions;
};

module.exports.wrapRefluxActions = RefluxErrorHandler;
```

To use it in actions.js:

```
var Reflux = require('reflux');
var WebUtils = require('web-utils.js');
var RefluxErrorHandler = require('reflux-error-handler.js');

var Actions = Reflux.createActions({
  getDataFromServer: { asyncResult: true } 
});

Actions.getDataFromServer.listenAndPromise(WebUtils.makeApiCall);

module.exports = RefluxErrorHandler(Actions);
```